# Not all pixels clipped when using UIView.layer.clipsToBounds = true in conjunction with CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, cabasicanimation

**What I'm doing:**
I am creating a music app. Within this music app, I have a music player that links with Apple Music and Spotify. The music player displays the current song's album art on a `UIImageView`. Whenever the song is playing, the `UIImageView` rotates (like a record on a record player).

**What my problem is:**
The album art for the `UIImageView` is square by default. I am rounding the `UIImageView`'s `layer`'s corners and setting `UIImageView.clipsToBounds` equal to `true` to make it appear as a circle. 
Whenever the `UIImageView` rotates, some of the pixels outside of the `UIImageView`'s `layer` (the part that is cut off after rounding the image) are bleeding through.

**Here is what the bug looks like:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJxX5PQc7Jo&feature=youtu.be

**My code:**
The `UIImageView` is rounded by setting its `layer`'s `cornerRadius` equal to `UIImageView.frame.height / 2` and setting `UIImageView.clipsToBounds = true`:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var albumArtImageView: UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        albumArtImageView.layer.cornerRadius = albumArtImageView.frame.height / 2
        albumArtImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //I've also tried the following code, and am getting the same behavior:
        /*
        albumArtImageView.layer.cornerRadius = albumArtImageView.frame.height / 2
        albumArtImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        albumArtImageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        */
    }
}
```

Whenever a button is pressed, the `UIImageView` begins to rotate. I've used the following `extension` to make `UIView`'s rotate:

```swift
extension UIView {
    func rotate(duration: Double = 1, startPoint: CGFloat) {
        if layer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey) == nil {
            let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")

            rotationAnimation.fromValue = startPoint
            rotationAnimation.toValue = (CGFloat.pi * 2.0) + startPoint
            rotationAnimation.duration = duration
            rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

            layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the following extension to end the rotation:

```swift
extension UIView {

    ...

    func stopRotating(beginTime: Double!, startingAngle: CGFloat) -> CGFloat? {
        if layer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey) != nil {
            let animation = layer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)!
            let elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - beginTime
            let angle = elapsedTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: animation.duration)/animation.duration

            layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((CGFloat(angle) * (2 * CGFloat.pi)) + startingAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            layer.removeAnimation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)
            return (CGFloat(angle) * (2 * CGFloat.pi)) + startingAngle
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is how these extension functions are used in the context of my view controller:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var songBeginTime: Double!
    var currentRecordAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
    var isPlaying = false

    ...

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isPlaying {
            if let angle = albumArtImageView.stopRotating(beginTime: songBeginTime, startingAngle: currentRecordAngle) {
                currentRecordAngle = angle
            }
            songBeginTime = nil
        } else {
            songBeginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            albumArtImageView.rotate(duration: 3, startPoint: currentRecordAngle)
        }
    }
}
```

So, all together, `MyViewController` looks something like this:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var albumArtImageView: UIImageView()

    var songBeginTime: Double!
    var currentRecordAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
    var isPlaying = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        albumArtImageView.layer.cornerRadius = albumArtImageView.frame.height / 2
        albumArtImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isPlaying {
            if let angle = albumArtImageView.stopRotating(beginTime: songBeginTime, startingAngle: currentRecordAngle) {
                currentRecordAngle = angle
            }
            songBeginTime = nil
        } else {
            songBeginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            albumArtImageView.rotate(duration: 3, startPoint: currentRecordAngle)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy your code into the project and I can reproduce this issue. But if you add the animation to another CALayer, that seems to resolve the issue.

```
extension UIView {

static var kRotationAnimationKey: String {
    return "kRotationAnimationKey"
}

func makeAnimationLayer() -> CALayer {

    let results: [CALayer]? = layer.sublayers?.filter({ $0.name ?? "" == "animationLayer" })

    let animLayer: CALayer
    if let sublayers = results, sublayers.count > 0 {
        animLayer = sublayers[0]
    }
    else {
        animLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        animLayer.name = "animationLayer"
        animLayer.frame = self.bounds
        animLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "imageNam")?.cgImage
        layer.addSublayer(animLayer)
    }

    return animLayer
}

func rotate(duration: Double = 1, startPoint: CGFloat) {
    if layer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey) == nil {

        let animLayer = makeAnimationLayer()

        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = startPoint
        rotationAnimation.toValue = (CGFloat.pi * 2.0) + startPoint
        rotationAnimation.duration = duration
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)
    }
}

func stopRotating(beginTime: Double!, startingAngle: CGFloat) -> CGFloat? {

    let animLayer = makeAnimationLayer()

    if animLayer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey) != nil {
        let animation = animLayer.animation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)!
        let elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - beginTime
        let angle = elapsedTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: animation.duration)/animation.duration
        animLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle) * (2 * CGFloat.pi) + startingAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        animLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: UIView.kRotationAnimationKey)
        return (CGFloat(angle) * (2 * CGFloat.pi)) + startingAngle
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s super encouraging. Let me try to implement it and get back to you!

Comment: Works perfectly. SO is making me wait two hours before awarding you your bounty, so you'll get it later today :)

Answer (score 1):

Clip to bounds does not include rounded corners.  Try using corner masking instead.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var albumArtImageView: UIImageView()

    var songBeginTime: Double!
    var currentRecordAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
    var isPlaying = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        albumArtImageView.layer.cornerRadius = albumArtImageView.frame.height / 2
        albumArtImageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isPlaying {
            if let angle = albumArtImageView.stopRotating(beginTime: songBeginTime, startingAngle: currentRecordAngle) {
                currentRecordAngle = angle
            }
            songBeginTime = nil
        } else {
            songBeginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            albumArtImageView.rotate(duration: 3, startPoint: currentRecordAngle)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this via `albumArtImageView.layer.cornerRadius = albumArtImageView.frame.height / 2`, `albumArtImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true`,`albumArtImageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]` and am getting the same behavior, unfortunately.